# Best practice for caching/garbage collection with database record-backed constructors in JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am in a scenario that seems like it would be fairly commonplace, but I haven't seen much written on the topic to date as far as best practices go.  I have a solution in place currently that is functional, but does not seem like the most efficient or optimal way of doing things.

In short, I have a database of several hundred thousand records and a nodejs process to interface with it.  When a client or system process wants to work on or use information from a record, it uses a constructor to load it into a Javascript object pseudo-class that has prototype methods attached to it for getting, setting, mutating, and otherwise working with the data in the record.  There is no clear time when a client process has "finished" working with a record, and it is possible that two clients or processes will want to work on the same record simultaneously.  So I need to keep a cached copy of the record stored in a global object to avoid async race conditions with the database.

Problem is, I have to clear out this cache periodically.  Currently, I have my own rudimentary garbage collector that sets a timeout of x number of minutes -- if no operations have been performed on that record object within that period, it deletes its own pointer from the global object to allow it to be picked up by GC. Next time a client needs to access it, it is loaded again from the DB and the timer begins anew.

While this is a currently functional process, I feel like as a general rule any time you have to employ timeouts and timers it is a clunky solution.  But it seems like this is a common scenario many designers would find themselves facing.  Is there an accepted best practice on how to create and destroy prototypical objects based on a large database set that can't fit entirely into memory at any given time?

Edit:

The current working method works basically as follows (simplified):

```
var records = {};

var Record = function(recordId) {
    this.lastOpTimestamp = Date.now();
    this.set = function(prop, value) {
        ....
        this.lastOpTimestamp = Date.now();
    }
    this.get = function(prop, value) {
        ....
        this.lastOpTimestamp = Date.now();
    }
}

records[recordId] = new Record(recordId);

function gcSweep() {
    var recordIds = Object.keys(records);
    for (var i=0;i < recordIds.length;i++) {
        if ((Date.now() - records[recordIds[i]].lastOpTimestamp) > 600000) {
            delete records[recordIds[i]];
        }
    }
}

setInterval(gcSweep, 10000);
```

Comment: Can you give the code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Edited original post to add example of current working method.